# How to Split the Options menu like Google chrome broswer

Tags: android, android-menu

How to split a menu like chrome browser as shown in the image:

[image]

This is my actual code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="materialtest.vivz.slidenerd.activities.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement dialogFragment and you can locate on the screen where you want.

Here is an example :

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-dialogfragment-tutorial/

You can change the position of the dialog. You can find it out how it works here :

[Changing position of the Dialog on screen android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467026/change-dialog-position-on-the-screen)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `DialogFragment` with a dialog window that has a limited size and biased to the top end of the screen using the gravity attribute.

Like normal fragments, `DialogFragment` takes in any custom layout in `onCreateView`.

**Animation:** The dialog window can have a customized style with `windowEnterAnimation` and `windowExitAnimation` to simulate the animation of showing/dismissing the menu.

Here's the demo:

```
class OptionsMenuDialog : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_options_menu, container, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        // adding dialog animation
        dialog.window!!.attributes!!.windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation
        return dialog
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        dialog!!.window!!.let {
            val params = it.attributes
            // Change the dialog size
            params.width = 600
            params.height = 1000
            // Bias the dialog to the top|end of the screen
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.END
            it.attributes = params
        }

    }

}
```

Java version:

```
public class OptionsMenuDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.dialog_options_menu, container,
                false
        );
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog =super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes = window.getAttributes();
        // Change dialog size
        attributes.width = 600;
        attributes.height = 1000;
        // Bias the dialog to the top|end of the screen
        attributes.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END;
        window.setAttributes(attributes);
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

The `DialogAnimation`:

```
    <style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_out</item>
    </style>
```

Animations:

anim_in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale
        android:duration="50"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

anim_out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale
        android:duration="50"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />
</set>
```

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bookmark"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bookmark"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_star_outline_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/refresh"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_refresh_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bookmark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/refresh">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                android:text="New tab"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can use `RecyclerView` for efficiency; just used `ScrollView` for simplicity.

**Edit:**

> `params.width = 600`, `params.height = 1000` both are overlapping
> small devices (small DP devices) in the size of the Options menu. Any
> better option to overcome this?

You'd create an XML value for both for different screen sizes; usually in `values/dimens.xml`

The default dimens.xml would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="dialog_height">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dialog_width">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes#alternative_layout_resources) show typical screen sizes that you would override their corresponding dimen resources:

> Here's how other smallest width values correspond to typical screen
> sizes:
>
> - 320dp: Typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800    hdpi, etc.)
> - 480dp: Large phone screen ~5" (480x800 mdpi)
> - 600dp: 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi)
> - 720dp: 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc.)

Android studio can generate that automatically with: File >> New >> Values Resource File

Then you can specify the desired screen width/height that you need to have a different size.

[image]

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android) has more in depth how to handle that.

Eventually you'd retrieve them in the dialog fragment like, and that will take care of the device width/height to pick the appropriate value:

```
// Kotlin
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    val density = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density
    val width = (resources.getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_width) * density).toInt()
    val height = (resources.getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_height) * density).toInt()

    dialog!!.window!!.let {
        val params = it.attributes
        // Change dialog size
        params.width = width
        params.height = height
        // Bias the dialog to the top|end of the screen
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.END
        it.attributes = params
    }

}

// Java

@Override
public void onStart() {
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes = window.getAttributes();

    float density = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int width = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_width) * density);
    int height = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_height) * density);

    attributes.width = width;
    attributes.height = height;
    // Bias the dialog to the top|end of the screen
    attributes.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END;
    window.setAttributes(attributes);
    super.onStart();
}
```

[image]

Comment: `params.width = 600`, `params.height = 1000` both are overlapping small devices (small `DP` devices) in the size of the Options menu. Any better option to overcome this?

Comment: @MDEV Please have a look at the updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much :) for great answer with great explanation. You answered more batter then expected and cleared all doubts. Finally I found full responsive Option menu. Again, Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey @MDEV You're welcome :) just noticed that Google chrome starts their animaition from the top right to bottom left; you'd change the anim_in like in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075491/9851608

Comment: I found that the new google chrome has a different animation. Thank you so much for that reference. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="materialtest.vivz.slidenerd.activities.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_new"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/action_new"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>

<!-- Second menu -->
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="materialtest.vivz.slidenerd.activities.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:title="@string/action_save"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_print"
        android:orderInCategory="103"
        android:title="@string/action_print"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```