# How to define dimens.xml for every different screen size in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-screen-support

When supporting different screen sizes (densities) in **Android** often the focus is on creating different layouts for every possible screen. I.E.

- ldpi
- mdpi
- hdpi
- xhdpi
- xxhdpi
- xxxhdpi

I designed a layout for an **xhdpi** screen as a reference, and defined it's **dimensions** in ***dimens.xml***. Now **I want to give support it to every possible screen size. How can I do that?**

As far as I know, I can use [this](http://androidpixels.net/) tool to figure out the proper ***dimens.xml*** for other screen sizes and add it to my project. Is this the right way to do it in my situation?

Another question, **do I only need to create *dimens.xml* for above screen dimensions? If yes then what is *`w820dp`*?**

Thanks for your help. I need to support **phones only** (not tablets or other devices).

Comment: Yes you have to create a different `dimesn.xml` files for different resolutions.

Comment: @PiyushGupta That will for all above dimensional screen? But what is `W820dp` is it something supporting different android version? Also can you suggest me any tutorial on supporting different screen on the basis of dimens.xml?

Comment: It is for tablet or for others. Otherwise as i said you need to create a different values folder.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

You have to create ***Different values folder for different screens*** .
Like

```
values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 

values-xxhdpi           5.5"  1080x1920 xxhdpi
values-xxxhdpi           5.5" 1440x2560 xxxhdpi

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

[image]

For more information you may visit here

> [Different values folders in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android)
>
> http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

**Edited**  By **[@humblerookie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2185582/humblerookie)**

You can make use of Android Studio plugin called [Dimenify](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio/plugin/9349-dimenify) to auto generate dimension values for other pixel buckets based on custom scale factors. Its still in beta, be sure to notify any issues/suggestions you come across to the developer.

Comment: shouldn't there be "values-sw480dp-hdpi" .xhdpi and xxhdpi and so on ? only 320dp have such in your answer.. please reply

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: You should mention the difference between Android <=3.2 and >3.2.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have created a studio plugin called Dimenify. This lets you create dimensions for other buckets easily. Could you add an edit with the same so others can make use of it?

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio/plugin/9349-dimenify

Comment: @humblerookie glad to hear that .You can edit my answer

Comment: @humblerookie Move ahead

Comment: is there's a way to create layout for specific dimension/density ?

Comment: @ralphspoon I did not try this

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya for sure, there will be new releases that will not be covered on those folders and/or may not be appropriate on certain folder.

Comment: What about landscape mode ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya How to support for android devices with aspect ratio 18:5:9. E.g: Samsung galaxy s8. The above different values folder doesn't for such devices.

Comment: is there a big difference if we only create values-sw320dp, values-sw600dp...et cetera instead of values-sw320dp-xhdpi, values-sw320dp-hdpi, values-sw320dp-mdpi? Is that suffix mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi at the end of values-swXXXdp that important?

Answer (score 57):

### Use [Scalable DP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Although making a different layout for different screen sizes is theoretically a good idea, it can get very difficult to accommodate for **all** screen dimensions, and pixel densities. Having over 20+ different `dimens.xml` files as suggested in the above answers, is not easy to manage at all.

**How To Use:**

To use `sdp`:

1. Include `implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'` in your `build.gradle`,
2. Replace any `dp` value such as `50dp` with a `@dimen/50_sdp` like so:

   ```
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
   ```

**How It Works:**

`sdp` scales with the screen size because it is essentially a huge list of different `dimens.xml` for every possible `dp` value.

[image]

**See It In Action:**

Here it is on three devices with widely differing screen dimensions, and densities:

[image]

Note that the `sdp` size unit calculation includes some approximation due to some performance and usability constraints.

Comment: Much obliged. This was really useful for me.

Comment: @Advait can you please tell me which values folder should i use for Samsung Edge 7 with 5.5 inch mobile with 2560x1440 resolution ?

Comment: @Advait currently i am using values-xxhdpi folder but problem is, it is taking same folder for 5, 5.5 & 6 screens same folder so there is scroll appears on 5 inch screens & 5.5. I don't want that. can you please help me in this ?

Comment: @Advait S values-xxhdpi  for  5.5"  1080x1920 & Also for 5.5" 1440x2560
I want different folder for  5.5" 1440x2560.

Comment: @ULHASPATIL exactly! I bumped with similar problem and don't understand how to resolve it. Did you find any solution for screen with similar inches and different pixel resolution?

Comment: Not working for all devices size will change when i open in to tablet

Comment: it is not clear how to convert negative values, in my case <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-40dp</item>

Comment: @AndrewGlukhoff you can try negative values up to negative 60 scalable-dp like so: `@dimen/_mins60sdp`

Answer (score 28):

we  want to see the changes of required view size in different screens.

We need to create a different values folders for different screens and put dimens.xml file based on screen densities.

I have taken one TextView and observed the changes when i changed dimens.xml in
different values folders.

Please follow the process

### normal - xhdpi \ dimens.xml

The below devices can change the sizes of screens when we change the normal - xhdpi \ dimens.xml

nexus 5X ( 5.2" * 1080 * 1920 : 420dpi )

nexus 6P ( 5.7" * 1440 * 2560 :  560dpi)

nexus 6 ( 6.0" * 1440 * 2560 :  560dpi)

nexus 5 (5.0", *1080* 1920 :  xxhdpi)

nexus 4 (4.7", 768 * 1280 :  xhdpi)

Galaxy nexus (4.7", 720 * 1280 :  xhdpi)

4.65" 720p ( 720 * 1280 : xhdpi )

4.7" WXGA ( 1280  * 720 : Xhdpi )

### Xlarge - xhdpi  \ dimens.xml

The below devices can change the sizes of screens when we change the Xlarge - xhdpi  \ dimens.xml

nexus 9 ( 8.9", 2048 * 1556 :  xhdpi)

nexus 10 (10.1", 2560 * 1600 : xhdpi)

### large - xhdpi  \ dimens.xml

The below devices can change the sizes of screens when we change the  large - xhdpi  \ dimens.xml

nexus 7 ( 7.0", 1200 * 1920: xhdpi)

nexus 7 (2012) (7.0", 800 * 1280 : tvdpi)

### The below screens are visible in " Search Generic Phones and Tablets "

### large - mdpi \ dimens.xml

The below devices can change the sizes of screens when we change the  large - mdpi  \ dimens.xml

5.1" WVGA ( 480 * 800 : mdpi )

5.4" FWVGA ( 480 * 854 : mdpi )

7.0" WSVGA (Tablet) ( 1024 * 600 : mdpi )

### normal - hdpi  \ dimens.xml

The below devices can change the sizes of screens when we change the  normal - hdpi  \ dimens.xml

nexus s ( 4.0", 480 * 800 : hdpi )

nexus one ( 3.7", 480 * 800: hdpi)

### small - ldpi  \ dimens.xml

The below devices can change the sizes of screens when we change the  small - ldpi \ dimens.xml

2.7" QVGA Slider ( 240 * 320 : ldpi )

2.7" QVGA ( 240 * 320 : ldpi )

### xlarge - mdpi \ dimens.xml

The below devices can change the sizes of screens when we change the  xlarge - mdpi  \ dimens.xml

10.1" WXGA ( tABLET) ( 1280 * 800 : MDPI )

### normal - ldpi \ dimens.xml

The below devices can change the sizes of screens when we change the  normal - ldpi   \ dimens.xml

3.3" WQVGA ( 240 * 400 : LDPI )

3.4" WQVGA ( 240 * 432 : LDPI )

### normal - hdpi \ dimens.xml

The below devices can change the sizes of screens when we change the  normal - hdpi    \ dimens.xml

4.0" WVGA ( 480 * 800 : hdpi )

3.7" WVGA ( 480 *  800 : hdpi )

3.7" FWVGA  Slider ( 480 *  854 : hdpi )

### normal - mdpi \ dimens.xml

The below devices can change the sizes of screens when we change the  normal - mdpi    \ dimens.xml

3.2" HVGA Slider ( ADP1 ) ( 320 * 480 : MDPI )

3.2" QVGA ( ADP2 ) ( 320 * 480 : MDPI )

Comment: So according to you the folders would then be named something like `values-normal-xhdpi`?

Comment: Yes, i agree with you, instead of write values- to all the files, i said, "create different values folders for different  text sizes". So please read the title. Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604335/all-devices-takes-resources-from-values-xxxhdpi-instead-of-values-folder it always takes values from the same folder for all devices

Answer (score 13):

There are nice libraries which will handle everything and reduce your pain. For using it, just add two dependencies in gradle:

```
 implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
 implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
```

After that, use `dimens` like this:

```
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_80sdp"
```

Comment: Here are the libraries for reference: [SDP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) and [SSP](https://github.com/intuit/ssp). And thanks for this precise answer!

Comment: This is also not perfect according to current time 2020

Comment: if you consider the ideal size as 5". it is fine to use these libraries.

Answer (score 8):

You have to create a different `values` folder for different screens and put `dimens.xml` file according to densities.

```
1) values

2) values-hdpi (320x480 ,480x800)

3) values-large-hdpi (600x1024)

4) values-xlarge (720x1280 ,768x1280 ,800x1280 ,Nexus7 ,Nexus10)

5) values-sw480dp (5.1' WVGA screen)

6) values-xhdpi (Nexus4 , Galaxy Nexus)
```

Comment: Where can I get the ration in between screen size? As I can see in the tool they defined everything in `ldpi`,`mdpi` manner

Comment: That will depends on your values folder which will be retreive values at most from it.

Comment: Do I need to mention `values-xxhdpi` for Nexus 6?

Comment: `320x480` is typical **mdpi**. So, put it either in `values` or in `values-mdpi`

Comment: What about landscape mode ?

Comment: it doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604335/all-devices-takes-resources-from-values-xxxhdpi-instead-of-values-folder it always takes values from the same folder for all devices

Answer (score 8):

I've uploaded a simple java program which takes your project location and the dimension file you want as input. Based on that, it would output the corresponding dimension file in the console. Here's the link to it:

https://github.com/akeshwar/Dimens-for-different-screens-in-Android/blob/master/Main.java

Here's the full code for the reference:

```
public class Main {


    /**
     * You can change your factors here. The current factors are in accordance with the official documentation.
     */
    private static final double LDPI_FACTOR = 0.375;
    private static final double MDPI_FACTOR = 0.5;
    private static final double HDPI_FACTOR = 0.75;
    private static final double XHDPI_FACTOR = 1.0;
    private static final double XXHDPI_FACTOR = 1.5;
    private static final double XXXHDPI_FACTOR = 2.0;

    private static double factor;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the location of the project/module");
        String projectPath = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Which of the following dimension file do you want?\n1. ldpi \n2. mdpi \n3. hdpi \n4. xhdpi \n5. xxhdpi \n6. xxxhdpi");

        int dimenType = in.nextInt();

        switch (dimenType) {
            case 1: factor = LDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            case 2: factor = MDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            case 3: factor = HDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            case 4: factor = XHDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            case 5: factor = XXHDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            case 6: factor = XXXHDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            default:
                factor = 1.0;
        }

        //full path = "/home/akeshwar/android-sat-bothIncluded-notintegrated/code/tpr-5-5-9/princetonReview/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml"
        //location of the project or module = "/home/akeshwar/android-sat-bothIncluded-notintegrated/code/tpr-5-5-9/princetonReview/"


        /**
         * In case there is some I/O exception with the file, you can directly copy-paste the full path to the file here:
         */
        String fullPath = projectPath + "/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml";

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fullPath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            modifyLine(strLine);
        }
        br.close();

    }

    private static void modifyLine(String line) {

        /**
         * Well, this is how I'm detecting if the line has some dimension value or not.
         */
        if(line.contains("p</")) {
            int endIndex = line.indexOf("p</");

            //since indexOf returns the first instance of the occurring string. And, the actual dimension would follow after the first ">" in the screen
            int begIndex = line.indexOf(">");

            String prefix = line.substring(0, begIndex+1);
            String root = line.substring(begIndex+1, endIndex-1);
            String suffix = line.substring(endIndex-1,line.length());


            /**
             * Now, we have the root. We can use it to create different dimensions. Root is simply the dimension number.
             */

            double dimens = Double.parseDouble(root);
            dimens = dimens*factor*1000;
            dimens = (double)((int)dimens);
            dimens = dimens/1000;
            root = dimens + "";

            System.out.println(prefix + " " +  root + " " + suffix );

        }

        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can put `dimens.xml` in

1) **values**

2) **values-hdpi**

3) **values-xhdpi**

4) **values-xxhdpi**

And give different sizes in `dimens.xml` within corresponding folders according to densities.

Comment: According do Android documentation small/normal/large are deprecated.

Comment: it doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604335/all-devices-takes-resources-from-values-xxxhdpi-instead-of-values-folder it always takes values from the same folder for all devices

Answer (score 2):

**The basic principle of getting more flexibility in your code is by encapsulating what is varying/changing (or what is highly likely to change).**

If your case dimensions are changing. So you start with moving your dimensions (the ones you think need to change) from XML code or from java/kotlin code to a file values/dimens.xml

For the context of this question.
You may have res folders by density qualifiers or by small-width qualifiers.

```
values/dimens.xml
values-ldpi/dimens.xml
values-hdpi/dimens.xml

values/dimens.xml
values-sw320dp/dimens.xml
values-sw320dp/dimens.xml
```

One important point to note here the items in values/dimens.xml will apply to screens smaller than the lowest breakpoint you have specified.

```
values/dimens.xml //smallest screen
values-sw320dp/dimens.xml //320dp or more till next breakpoint folder
values-sw360dp/dimens.xml//360dp or more till next breakpoint folder
```

**Another important point to note is that a high pixel density device may have a small screen.** So be sure whether you want to specify density qualifier or screen width qualifier.

---

Some further briefing for those who are new to this aspect.

You can add qualifiers to different resource folders such as values, drawable, and layout.

These qualifiers may represent a language (-en,-hi) ,an orientation (-land,-port), or screen size range (-ldpi,-hdpi).

The naming convention has a hierarchy of qualifiers and qualifiers must be added in that order only.

```
    values-en-hdpi (it cannot be values-hdpi-en)
    values-en-land-hdpi (it cannot be values values-hdpi-en-land or any other order)
layout-hdpi
```

The order is documented in [Table 2 at this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#table2)

Some qualifiers represent absolute values whereas others like ldpi,hdpi represent breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to view more: Here's a [link](https://design.google.com/devices/) for a list of devices (tablet, mobile, watches), including `watch`,`chromebook`, `windows` and `mac`. Here you can find the density, dimensions, and etc. Just based it in here, it's a good resource if your using an emulator too.

If you click a specific item, it will show more details in the right side. 
[image: sample]

Since it's `Android` , I will post related to it. 
[image: sample1]

[image: sample2]

~ It's better if you save a copy of the web. To view it offline.

Answer (score 1):

Android 3.2 introduces a new approach to screen sizes,the numbers describing the screen size are all in “dp” units.Mostly we can use

**smallest width dp:** the smallest width available for application layout in “dp” units; this is the smallest width dp that you will ever encounter in any rotation of the display.

To create one right click on **res** >>> **new** >>> **Android resource directory**

From **Available qualifiers** window move **Smallest Screen Width** to **Chosen qualifiers**

In **Screen width** window just write the "dp" value starting from you would like Android Studio to use that dimens.

Than change to **Project** view,right click on your new created resource directory

**new** >>> **Values resource file** enter a new file name **dimens.xml** and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for explaining on how to actually create these folders.