# Using layout in android xml

Tags: android

Which is the layout to use which doesn't have a difference in different screen sizes. Linear layout or relative. I had a relative layout and when I run the app on a 4' phone, the icons were way closer. In a 5' phone the icons were a bit away. What's the best way to have a constant XML which doesn't change by screen size. 
For example.
I had this app in linear layout which contained 3 images in horizontal orientation. In the design view the icons were perfectly same and equidistant. But on the device, the third icon was smaller. Why

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android

Comment: Linear layout is best for supporting all screen's and maintain each view weight

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve perfect layout for every device with just single layout file. For best results you should make different layout files for different folders used with images designed accordingly. For more information read Android Developers' tutorial from the following link

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

Over and all, you need to create different layouts/drawables for supporting all the screens. It depends on your requirement, say for example, if you would want to include 2 buttons in small screen and 4 buttons on large screens then obvious you have to create different layouts.

If you would want to display same number of buttons in all screens then I would suggest you to prepare different set of images/drawables and include them in your project. Here you don't need to do anything other than placing images in particular drawable folders.

One more thing, If its a plain background then you can create 9-patch image so that it can stretch with whatever size you want or your device supports.

More study:

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
2. http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html
3. http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html
4. http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html