# How to increase font size when going from mobile to tablet

Tags: android, button, screen

I want to know whether I can make a common app for mobile and tablet. Right now I have developed an app for mobile which has buttons. But when I go to tablet the button size remains the same. I want to increase button size as we go to tablet.

Comment: check this logic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android/32861248#32861248

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, you are encouraged to make better use of more space in tablet, e.g. use different layout with [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) for different screen size.

However, **if you just want to make things bigger for tablets you can simply use a [resource qualifier in android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules)**. In your case, create another  values directory in the res folder, e.g. values-sw600dp for tablet with smallest width from 600dp, and then put dimens.xml inside the folder.

Inside that **res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Customization of dimensions in res/values/dimens.xml -->
    <dimen name="button_layout_width">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_layout_height">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_text_size">20sp</dimen>   
</resources>
```

Also, put the same items into the default dimens.xml in **res/values/dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default dimension for phone  -->
    <dimen name="button_layout_width">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_layout_height">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_text_size">12sp</dimen>        
</resources>
```

Then use them in your layout xml file

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button_layout_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
    android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
    android:text="My Button"
    />
```

The system will use the correct values for you based on the qualifier. In your case, choose correct dimension based on the smallest width of the device your app run on.

Learn more about the [resource qualifier here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Comment: You can extend this also for Portrait and Landscape orientations

Comment: Yes, with res/values-sw600dp-land/, and so much more with resource qualifier.