# Android Wear: What is resources.getDimension(R.dimen.digital_x_offset)

Tags: android, wear-os, watchface

Where does the value associated with this "x_offset" come from or what does it represent? And is it an absolute or relative to width value?

Edit:
the default value is 15dp which is about a third of the text size. (info form Clement Amarnath's link: https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/Wearable/res/values/dimens.html)

Edit2: Specifically, I would like to know if there are any cases where a programmer should use this value instead of generating their own values based on screen size and density?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where does the value associated with this "x_offset" come from

digital_x_offset value is coming from dimens.xml

Please refer the below documentation

https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/Wearable/res/values/dimens.html

---

**EDIT**

Read this post [How to define dimens.xml for every different screen size in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android) it provides a good amount of info on dimens.xml

---

Offset helps us in placing our frame in the main frame, we can position our frame from the left, right, top or bottom in the main frame/window.

`<dimen name="digital_x_offset">15dp</dimen>` This statement of xoffset in dimens.xml means it is the distance from the left side of the screen/frame/window.

`<dimen name="digital_y_offset">80dp</dimen>` This statement of yoffset in dimens.xml means it is the distance from the top of the screen.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link to the default values, that helps some. It tells me that the value is scales with screen density but not user preference. Yet I would like to know where the value comes from conceptually.

Comment: thank you for the link to How to define dimens.xml for every different screen size in android? It is a good discussion on how to address different screen sizes, but I found no mention of what the x_offset signified.

Comment: @kjl - I have added details about offset, please go thru it, Also please spend more time on reading documentation.

Comment: Is it based on how much the screen moves for screen burn, the size of text characters, the expected size of scroll bars, etc, or just a recommended aesthetic for margins?