# Android Studio : My Layout appears Differently when the app installed on different screen size Help me someone

Tags: android, android-layout

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff8c00"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.vnsilva.mycalculator.Calculator"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_calculator">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#121212"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:maxLength="17"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:numeric="integer"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:maxWidth="90dp"
        android:onClick="onClickNumber"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn7"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:maxWidth="90dp"
        android:onClick="onClickNumber"
        android:text="8"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn8"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:maxWidth="90dp"
        android:onClick="onClickNumber"
        android:text="9"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:onClick="onClickNumber"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn7"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:onClick="onClickNumber"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:onClick="onClickNumber"
        android:text="6"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn4"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:onClick="onClickNumber"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn3"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:onClick="onClickNumber"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnEqual"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnMult"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnMult"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:onClick="onClickNumber"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:onClick="onClickClear"
        android:text="AC"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:onClick="onClickNumber"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEqual"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn3"
        android:background="#ff8d02"
        android:onClick="onClickEqual"
        android:text="="
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn9"
        android:background="#ff8d02"
        android:maxWidth="90dp"
        android:onClick="onClickOperator"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn6"
        android:background="#ff8d02"
        android:onClick="onClickOperator"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMult"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn9"
        android:background="#ff8d02"
        android:onClick="onClickOperator"
        android:text="x"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDiv"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnprcnt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn9"
        android:background="#ff8d02"
        android:onClick="onClickOperator"
        android:text="÷"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnprcnt"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="178dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:onClick="onClickOperator"
        android:text="%"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnprcnt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnClear"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnClear"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:onClick="onClickOperator"
        android:text="^"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnEqual"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnEqual"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:onClick="onClickNumber"
        android:text="."
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you have to manage dimen.xml file for different screen types,
refer this link : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android

Comment: What do you mean by "appears differently"? It should and will appear differently on different screen sizes. If you have any specific problem, please post a description or some screenshots.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/v5hhev/9 - Screenshot in my phone
http://tinypic.com/r/j8ju6d/9 - Screenshot in my friends phone whose screen size is larger than me!

Comment: @Bhoomit_BB can you change the above code and give me? pls!

Comment: Use linear layout with weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give  fixed heights and widths in dp as in( android:layout_width="90dp") , the view will change according to screen size.Try using layout_width="wrap_content",same with layout_height.