# Android Studio Dimension for margin supporting on all screens

Tags: android, android-studio, screen, margin, dimensions

When tried to assign  a margin and padding for all screens. Defaultly it is taken from the dimen.xml folder. It has not taken the appropriate dimension file. So that our design is inaccurate.

In the Eclipse, values-ldpi, values-mdpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi folder is available. So the assigning problem is not there. From the android studio, only having the s2600dp, sw720dp, large-xhdpi and large-xxhdpi folder. Here only I have struggled to assigning a margin. Can you please explain it how can i assign a margin in the android studio for all screens?

Comment: Can you post your values-* holder?

Comment: Maybe this link is usable
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android