# Support Multiscreen Android issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want support android device from *4.7 inch to 10 inch tablet* in my application. Its only supporting *portrait* mode.

I have created layout folder and all layout is in it. I am using dimen for values for it. I have created *values-sw320dp,values-sw480dp,values-sw600dp and values-sw820dp* folders and given according dimen in it.

But now when I choose device **android 4.7(Nexsus S)**, its taking values from **values-sw600dp.** What I am missing and whats wrong in my project ?

Thanks

Comment: use values-sw480dp-hdpi folder and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the developer Docs. You can find information for supporting screen sizes here

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Also Dimension values list originally given here

[How to define dimens.xml for every different screen size in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android)

Hope it Helps