# How to specify fixed layout_marginLeft for smartphones and wrap_content for tablet for NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have the below navigation drawer and I want to give `layout_marginLeft` as  -64dp for smartphones and `wrap_content` for tablets. 
Please let me know how to do that?I don't want to create separate `laytout.xml` files for smartphone and tablets i.e I have only one `layout.xml` file. As of now I am specifying different dimension in  `dimes.xml`  files which are created for smartphones and tabs.

```
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how to create different `dimes.xml` files for [multiple screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) (If you don't know that have a look in [How to define dimens.xml for every different screen size in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android)) your problem should be how to set `android:layout_marginLeft` in the specific xml file using dimen value.

You can try this way

for `wrap_content`>
    `<dimen name="your_value">-2dp</dimen>`

for `match_parent`>
`<dimen name="your_value">-1dp</dimen>`

and set  `android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/your_value"`

Comment: Thanku for repay...but your approach is not working... its giving error as android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x10

Comment: @kumar have you given the values in **dp** just giving a value will throw that error, this works for me very well, next double check you have given the values for all your xmls not only for a one

Answer (score -1):

You Just have to create 5 layouts file for all screen sizes with same name(of layout file) and store it into different folder In (hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi).

Comment: Read and answer @Kumari op says **i dont want to create separate laytout.xml files for smartphone and tablets**

Comment: Then you can make dimens for different screen resolution

Comment: good you might wish to update your answer with a related example :)

Comment: for tablet you have to create values-sw720dp and values-sw600dp and make a dimens.xml inside it and declare your reulation

Comment: Are getting solution or not

Comment: declare  the value and show it in your example thats what op is asking, btw   no offence you might wish to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer