# Android different margin_Top dp in every size of screen

Tags: android

I actually have fixed `margin_Top`, which is `50dp`. But when I tested with different size of screens, the `imageview` will not be in the same position as each other. Therefore, I searched something about how to adjust the `dimen.xml` in `values`. But I have no idea how to edit, create new `dimen.xml`, and calculate the size in different screens.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  tools:context="com.example.mygames.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ProgressBar

    android:id="@+id/circularProgressbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="750dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
    android:secondaryProgress="100"
    android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/whitecircle"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="25%"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/circularProgressbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Progress" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My `dimen.xml`:

```
<resources>
 <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
 <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="appbar_padding_top">8dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: Try this library.Maybe it's useful to you.        https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: I don't need to download the code?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android

Comment: Thanks, but I have checked this many times, and I still have no idea how to edit or create anything

Answer (score 0):

This is done in a different way.
Like you can put a layout for landscape mode in a folder `layout-land` you can put values files (like `dimens.xml`) in different folders too.
Example is the `values-w820p` folder which is created in a default project.
the `-wxxxx` is the screen dimension (for tablets and the like).

So you just need copies of your dimens.xml in different values folders, each containing the values for the screen size.

I am not native english, I hope you understand what I mean.

Android will automatically pick the file which fits the currently running device best.

Read through the resource features here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Here is a simple example:

in your `values` folder is dimens.xml which holds

```
<dimen name="examplewidth">50dp</dimen>
```

now create a folder `values-mdpi` and just **copy** the dimens.xml file into that folder.

in that copy you change the value from `50dp` to... say 20dp.
Then `examplewidth` will be 50dp on all devices except on low-res screens (mdpi) where it will resolve to 20dp. Automatically you do not need to write a single line of code.

Comment: It would be highly appreciated if you could give example, as I have read many sources, and none of them teach how to do it step by step. Thanks

Comment: The comment given by @rafsanahmad007 is what you are looking for. I will edit my answer with one example, but its really as easy as copying a file... there is no black magic involved.