# Android value dimen values-sw360dp-xxhdpi no call

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to create folder `values-sw360dp-xhdpi` with     `<dimen name="dimen_120dp">120.00dp</dimen>`
but when I call `dimen`. I have a log :

> check autosize:height:592.0__width:360.0__density:2.0__dimen:244.0

It call values-sw720dp-mdpi.
**I have add :**

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

I don't know why not call `values-sw360dp-xhdpi`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android/32861248#32861248

Comment: when call sw360dp success. but when desty xhpi no result i want