# How to use 1080x1920: 420 dpi - Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-devices

I am new in android development.
I have created an android application most of the devices design are looking fine.
1080x1920 resolution devices working fine. But, some devices Nexus 5x and LeEco-2 (both having same resolution) the designs (UI) are not looking as expected in these devices.

How which resource folder I need to use for these devices ?

[image]

Comment: see logic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android/32861248#32861248

Answer (score 1):

call this `method` to know which screen size is actually the device is! some devices get value from `xxxhdpi` some get from `sw800dp` (or any other `smallest width` folder)

```
 public int differentDensityAndScreenSize(Context context) {
        int value = 20;
        String str = "";
        if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
            switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                    str = "small-ldpi";
                    value = 20;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                    str = "small-mdpi";
                    value = 20;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                    str = "small-hdpi";
                    value = 20;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                    str = "small-xhdpi";
                    value = 20;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                    str = "small-xxhdpi";
                    value = 20;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
                    str = "small-xxxhdpi";
                    value = 20;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
                    str = "small-tvdpi";
                    value = 20;
                    break;
                default:
                    str = "small-unknown";
                    value = 20;
                    break;
            }

        } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
            switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                    str = "normal-ldpi";
                    value = 82;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                    str = "normal-mdpi";
                    value = 82;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                    str = "normal-hdpi";
                    value = 82;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                    str = "normal-xhdpi";
                    value = 90;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                    str = "normal-xxhdpi";
                    value = 96;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
                    str = "normal-xxxhdpi";
                    value = 96;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
                    str = "normal-tvdpi";
                    value = 96;
                    break;
                default:
                    str = "normal-unknown";
                    value = 82;
                    break;
            }
        } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
            switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                    str = "large-ldpi";
                    value = 78;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                    str = "large-mdpi";
                    value = 78;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                    str = "large-hdpi";
                    value = 78;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                    str = "large-xhdpi";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                    str = "large-xxhdpi";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
                    str = "large-xxxhdpi";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
                    str = "large-tvdpi";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
                default:
                    str = "large-unknown";
                    value = 78;
                    break;
            }

        } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
            switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                    str = "xlarge-ldpi";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                    str = "xlarge-mdpi";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                    str = "xlarge-hdpi";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                    str = "xlarge-xhdpi";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                    str = "xlarge-xxhdpi";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
                    str = "xlarge-xxxhdpi";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
                    str = "xlarge-tvdpi";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
                default:
                    str = "xlarge-unknown";
                    value = 125;
                    break;
            }
        }
// The Toast will show the Device falls in Which Categories.
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return value;
    }
```