# How to make layout for diffrent screen sizes using Relative Layout for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, screen-size

I have coded the whole app and designed all the layouts in Relative Layout, but now I want to make it compatible with all the screen sizes.

Comment: use constraint layout.

Comment: 1. Use dimens.xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android

Comment: As @SohailZahid mentioned you can use Constraint Layout https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: @SohailZahid  constraint layout was the easiest and the best option .. thankz bhai

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using the [percent relative layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

It offers the following attributes which you can use to set dimensions accordingly.

- layout_widthPercent
- layout_heightPercent
- layout_marginPercent
- layout_marginLeftPercent

etc.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases Android will automatically resize your layout to fit the screen. However, if you want to ensure that elements will be placed the way you define them to be then use different layouts for different layouts for different screen size. The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra-large screen should go in layout-xlarge/. [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: How to call the specific layout depending upon Screen-size ...I mean how to detect the Screen-size ..any pre-defined function for that?

Comment: Thankz for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning weights to UI components. Works like charm, not matter what screen size is

example

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```