# changing display size of android app

Tags: android, android-layout

My developed Android app works well on my phone, and I have used linear layout, and set the pixel as `dp`.

However, there is a setting in my phone, which can change the screen display size, I set it to large, and some of my layout is outside of the screen.

I tried to look up at the official document, but I found that it said usually setting change won't affect.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: u need to share screens for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can create dimension xml file for different screen density pixels. Refer this link for more details 
[How to define dimens.xml for every different screen size in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android)