# width change with narrow screen sizes

Tags: android, screen

I am a new programmer. I having trouble with some of the screens my grid [new screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGi2C.png)  appears as wired rows (maybe because the width of the screen is narrow ) . I've uploaded picture of my problem and my code. 
where did I go wrong? hw can I fix it?

[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXksy.png)

```
   <GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gameTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <!-- the 16 buttons -->
    <!-- 1:     (0,0) -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:onClick="choosePlace"
        android:tag="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Different values folder for different screens as in following answer:
[How to define dimens.xml for every different screen size in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android#32861248)

Then write different sizes for buttons in each dimen.xml

```
<dimen name="btn_width">50dp</dimen>

<dimen name="btn_width">30dp</dimen>

<dimen name="btn_width">20dp</dimen>
```

And then in your xml use

```
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_width"
```

Comment: in those folders: /res/values-sw320dp/dimens.xml   /res/values-sw480dp/dimens.xml   /res/values-sw700dp/dimens.xml   /res/values-sw800dp/dimens.xml . For examle. "sw480dp" says that folder will be used for screens which have 480dp+ screen width

Comment: I opened new value resource file name values-sw480dp, how do I open inside of it the dimen folder? I tried to stand on the values-sw480dp file and than add the dimen I tried all the 3 options (resource file/ file/ directory ) but I can't see it. I did not understand the link how to define dimens you have entered and try to search it myself and I still confuse

Comment: In Android Studio expand values folder, then right button click on it, then new->Values resource file. File name: **dimen**, then add in Available qualifiers "Screen Width" set screen width to 420 for example, directory name must change to "values-w420dp" then press "Ok". In new "dimen.xml" declare `<dimen name="btn_width">SIZE_TO_420DP_SCREEN</dimen>`

Comment: thank you for your help. I did open a dimen folder but don't know how to add  in Available qualifiers "Screen Width"

Comment: Right click on "values" folder in Android studio, then new->Values resource file

Comment: really that you for trying to help. I did what you wrote (see new screen shot in my question) but now I have this kind of problem in all of my screens (only rows).can you take a look in the new screen shot I uploaded? maybe I did something wrong there..

Comment: I think you should declare diferent GridLayout margins for all screens too

Comment: Thank you Andrey your helped me a  lot! :)

Comment: Thank you very much Andrey. could you please advice if there is anyway to center the grid not by margin in every screen? I tried to center it by code but it didn't help to center the grid

Comment: Try  put your GridLayout in FrameLayout and add atribute `android:layout_gravity="center" to GridLayout