# For which screen density is generated android default dimens?

Tags: android

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android) answer to handle dimens for all screen sizes, but I have misunderstanding, can anyone explain me, for which screen density is generated android default dimens?

And also if I'm trying to handle `xxhdpi` for both `1080x1920` and `1440x2560`, how should I do that?

Because I'm allowed to build only one dimension with the name `values-xxhdpi` or it is not even a keyword?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: **mdpi**, of course. mdpi has been, is and will always be the *default density*.

Comment: Don't confuse screen density with screen size.

Comment: @ModularSynth thx,and how  to handle xxhdpi for both 1080x1920 and 1440x2560?

Comment: use either the `w` or `h` switches. ie: `w1080` and `w1440`. You might want to read the official docs, though.

Comment: @ModularSynth  so values-xxhdpi is not a keyword?

Comment: It's a switch. But in your case it's not enough, because you want to distinguish between 2 different `xxhdpi`. Again, go through the official docs.

Comment: @ModularSynth w1080 and w1440 will work both on horizontal and vertical device?

Comment: Don't do the help-vampire. Find the official docs by googling for `android supporting multiple screens`

Comment: @ModularSynth Ok, thanks