# How to calculate dp for LDPI,MDPI,HDPI,XXHDPI,XXXHDPI in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i have screen which is deisgned in XHDPI .

I have to convert all padding ,margin value of `dp` into `LDPI`,`MDPI`,`HDPI`,`XXHDPI`,`XXXHDPI`

Can any one please suggest me how  i will calculate `dp` value for follwing screen suppose i have `paddingTop` in `xhdpi` is `56dp` then what value we have give for `ldpi`,`mdpi`, `xxhdpi` and  `xxxhdpi`

please suggest me.

Comment: Give it a try. Is this you are looking for.? http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/

Comment: 56 i have input  and try to convert it but i am able to get value

Comment: i want to know how we calculate for ldpi,xxhdpi,mdpi for 56dp which base of xhdpi

Comment: when you use `xxxdp` in your layout file it will be automatically scaled so you dont need to know the value in pixels, what do you need it for?

Comment: but we have to set margin top value for xxhdpi like i have set xhdpi 50dp

Comment: i dint understand  i  just want to know if i have puted 50dp in xhdpi then what value we have to put ldpi,mdpi, xxhdpi and  xxxhdpi @ pskink

Comment: also `50dp` - it is independent of screen density

Answer (score 5):

## Density-independent pixel (dp)

> A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
> The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: **px = dp * (dpi / 160)**. For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different densities.

If you want to know what's 56dp in xhdpi, that's 56dp in ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi as well - as the definition says, it's **density-independent pixels**.

When you work with a design, you want to know one thing:

#### What's the baseline scale for the design?

Some quick answers: It's usually 1x, 2x or in rare cases 3x

Android defines the following densities:

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

There are some rare cases in-between, like tvdpi, but in 99% of the cases you can just simply ignore those.

When designers say 1x, they usually refer to **mdpi**, 2x (or retina) refers to **xhdpi** and 3x design is done in **xxhdpi**.

Once you know the baseline, you know **how to translate the pixel values from the design document to dip** *(density-independent pixel)*.

The formula is quite simple, but if you doubt yourself, feel free to try one of the online converter tools:

- https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter
- http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/

The formula is as follows: **dp = px / (dpi / 160)** where *dpi* is the current screen density and *px* is the value in the base (1x) density.

Or the [other way around](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels).

Also, remember to read the [Best Practices](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#best-practices) from the Android Developers page!

---

If you still end up using px in your dimensions file which are not recommended, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861248/2759296) to know how to create different values folder for different screens.

Comment: i dint understand  i  just want to know if i have puted 50dp in xhdpi then what value we have to put ldpi,mdpi, xxhdpi and  xxxhdpi @anthonymonori

Comment: @ManojKumar please read the first line after the quote on the top of my answer: "If you want to know what's 56dp in xhdpi, that's 56dp in ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi as well - as the definition says, it's density-independent pixels."