# Layout for screen size 18.5x9

Tags: java, android, layout, size, resolution

I want to create a layout.xml for Samsung galaxy S8. I tried to set it up with a Screen size of  *18.5x9* .. but when I start the App it didn't fit.

I also tried to work with the resolution *(2220x1080 / 2960x1080)* but this didn't work too.

Any idea to set the screen size of one layout.xml to exactly the size of the phone (its also working for *large/xlarge* phones.. so why not for the s8)?

Comment: Kindly check logic https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861248/3395198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung galaxy s8 resolution is 1440 x 2560 pixels. So, if you want to create layout for this, you need to maintain your values and drawables folders for xxxhdpi. you can create your dimen file for xxxhdpi layouts.

For drawables :

```
drawable-ldpi        //240x320
drawable-mdpi        //320x480
drawable-hdpi        //480x800
drawable-xhdpi       //720x1280
drawable-xxhdpi      //1080X1920
drawable-xxxhdpi     //1440X2560
```

For Values :

```
values-ldpi\dimens.xml
values-mdpi\dimens.xml
values-hdpi\dimens.xml
values-xhdpi\dimens.xml
values-xxhdpi\dimens.xml
values-xxxhdpi\dimens.xml
```