# Layout weight not working properly in different screen size devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an app [quiz app] and i placed 4 buttons as option for each question.
Buttons Code something like.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom|center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/QNasLay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.0dip"
        android:layout_margin="2.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/qll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2.0">

            <TextView
                android:textSize="14.0dip"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/taOpt5"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100.0dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:maxWidth="110.0dip"
                android:maxHeight="80.0dip"
                android:minWidth="90.0dip"
                android:minHeight="60.0dip"
                android:hint="Option 2"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

            <TextView
                android:textSize="14.0dip"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/taOpt6"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100.0dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:maxWidth="110.0dip"
                android:maxHeight="80.0dip"
                android:minWidth="90.0dip"
                android:minHeight="60.0dip"
                android:hint="Option 2"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2.0">

            <TextView
                android:textSize="14.0dip"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/taOpt7"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100.0dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:maxWidth="110.0dip"
                android:maxHeight="80.0dip"
                android:minWidth="90.0dip"
                android:minHeight="60.0dip"
                android:hint="Option 2"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

            <TextView
                android:textSize="14.0dip"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/taOpt8"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100.0dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:maxWidth="110.0dip"
                android:maxHeight="80.0dip"
                android:minWidth="90.0dip"
                android:minHeight="60.0dip"
                android:hint="Option 2"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

But when i run the app with different screen size devices its something like bellow image.
[Image Here](https://ibb.co/ccQgSm)

Any idea how can i solve this problem.

I am expecting the layout design something like [this image](https://ibb.co/mLV1tR)

Comment: Which expected layout do you want ?

Comment: LinearLayout? I wrap above layout in linearlayout with height and width wrap_content and the whole xml is called in between NastedScrollllView height wrap_content width fill parent.

Comment: No, I want to know the design of this screen. Ex: you want the four buttons are placed in horizontal, vertical, etc.

Comment: @LQGioan i update the question please check.

Comment: Show the detail xml code about it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you are working for different screen sizes. You can put your height and widths in different values folders so that it look good in tab mobile as well old mobile 4" screens size.
- remove height and use weight or different values folder with different dimens for different screen sizes. You can find it here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861248/6891563

- Second remove this code from your xml because it is making layout not flexible.

  ```
          android:maxWidth="110.0dip"
          android:maxHeight="80.0dip"
          android:minWidth="90.0dip"
          android:minHeight="60.0dip"
  ```
- Bonus Suggestion

Always use `layout_width` 0 dp with weight property for better performance.

Like if Linearlayout horizontal and child has weight then use `layout_width` 0dp

and if Linearlayout vertical and child has weight then use `layout_height` 0dp

Comment: Thankx you very much.

Comment: @PrankoKaur Added some suggestion, you should see.