# Dimensions always picked up from higher resolution directory for example values-xxhdpi for all the phones

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I have separate values directories like values-mdpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi and values-xxhdpi

But in all screen resolution phones, dimens are picked from values-xxhdpi
if I delete values-xxhdpi then it picks up from values-xhdpi

I have tried it on large and xlarge phones

Could be an old and common question but I didn't find any working simple solution

Comment: `values and values-mdpi` these are **synonims**.

Comment: Kling Klang, can you suggest me how to handle this case? I have a phone which is 207ppi I want to have separate dimens for this phones alone

Comment: What is the OS version that your phone is running?

Comment: Rename the non mdpi folder to `values-nodpi`.

Comment: @Sagar It is 4.4

Comment: Have you tried Kling Klang's approach to create `values-nodpi`?

Comment: I did now it is only picking from no-dpi

Comment: @SreedhuMadhu try to create folder `values-sw320dp` or `values-sw480` for mdpi

Comment: @Sagar values-sw320dp works fine thank you

Comment: Great. I will update it as answer

Comment: I have updated it as answer, help me to approve so that others can get benefit from it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values` and `values-mdpi` are virtually the same. If you want to create a differentiation create **`values-sw320dp`** which will be taken into account for mdpi.

You can refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should write down how it started working for me,

First of all values-mdpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi, values-xxhdpi are not working as expected those mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi are working fine with mipmap and drawables.

In case of values, independent of phone resolution it is picking from the highest resolution, in my case values-xxhdpi if I delete it then it picks up from values-xhdpi

I tried it on a mdpi and hdpi phones still it is picking from highest resolution one

As @Sagar mentioned sw320dp seems working for me
so I created values-sw320dp, values-sw360dp and values-sw400dp now it started picking dimens from respective directories based on phone's resolution.