# Responsive Layout Design

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design, android-constraintlayout

I finished the java codes and function of my little project. At the end, i check to support a big amount of android devices according to their size. But it was fail.

While researching, i understand that i should use `sp` for textsizes and `dp` for all other parameters. The layout -xml- is existed via `sp` and `dp`. But it is not like that i expected.

I create a new project for example.

My xml; (in `ConstraintLayout`)

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textSize="105sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
    android:text="Check"
    android:textSize="160sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

For 1080 x 1920 xxhdpi; [Click here to see layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixL1W.png)

For 1440 x 2960 hdpi(samsung galaxy s8 ) [Click here to see layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RUAK.png)

In galaxy s8, elements are really small and there is problem in view. I guess that i misunderstand a basic concept. Can you clear up my mind please?

Comment: you have to know screen dimension for all device support, have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android)

Comment: 1. of all you use bias. Remove it if you dont need. 2. You use contrains additional to margins. Remove margins, do the possitions only with contrains. 3. Depending on Device font/Size and theme, every ui app will look a little different. Overview about CL: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/ As hakan said, dimensions could be usefull, but you dont need them if you design a perfect contrain layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing something here: when you set `android:layout_marginTop="72dp"` the 72dp wil lbe interpreted the same way in both layout files.

A solution is to use dimens instead of values directly in your xml file.

Watch here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861248/5778152

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful at screen size and pixel density.

The best way to treat all screen sizes is to use `ConstraintLayout`, or `weightSum` in `LinearLayout` (but it slows UI performance). This will help you keep the same position of the elements on all screens.

Pixel density is harder to treat. For text size, for example, I find it useful to use different `dimens` files.
Right click `values` folder and click `Values resource file`, put the name `dimens` and then choose `Density` from the left. There you can select what density you like to treat. In each file you make you can make a text size with the same name, like this:

```
<dimen name="normal_text_size">15sp</dimen>
```

and each time you set a text size use this tag. This way depending on the phone density the appropriate text size will be automatically selected.

You can read about `ConstraintLayout` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

Read about screen size [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

And about pixel density [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities)