# How to maintain equal size of cardview items in a recyclerview without hard coding the size?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, responsive-design, grid-layout, android-cardview

[Image of list I wish to replicate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duzm7.png)

I am designing an app that displays a list similar to the one displayed in the image. I actually will be implementing 3 lists of the same kind stacked below each other vertically(Each row representing output from 3 different API calls, So basically I have 3 different horizontal-recycler views). My problem is how do I maintain uniform width and height across cards in one row as well as across the 3 rows. The API response from the 3 sources that is mapped into the 3 rows, returns images of different sizes for each row. Is hard coding the size the only solution?If so, how will I maintain the size across different screen sizes?

Comment: What do you define as "uniform" size? Using `dp` size is safest bet - UI might require more scrolling on devices with small screens, but it should stay readable. Using percent-of-screen size dimensions are not recommended for anything with text because it might become illegible on smaller screens while becoming over-sized (and stretches out small images) on tablets etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Is hard coding the size the only solution?

It is best fit solution for your requirement. For that you can make a dimen.

```
<dimen name="card_size">100dp</dimen>
```

And give your card size in every item layout like.

```
<CardView
   android:layout_width="@dimen/card_size"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/card_size"
   />
```

> how will I maintain the size across different screen sizes?

**Now second thing is to make responsive card size for different screens.**

For that you have two options.

1. (Long historical method) Put dimen- card_size in every screen value folder. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32860815/6891563).
2. (Short method) I prefer this method.

In this you will use [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) library and just use `100sdp` instead of `100dp`.

See sdp library work.

[image]