# Best practice to do layout designing for 4 inch 5 inch ,5.5,6 inch phone

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked many times but what is the best practice to design layout for multiple screen size My Graphic designer has created designs in  360 width * 640 height how can i calculate the values of margin and padding for all views in accordance to 5 inch and 4 inch phone and use those value for pizel perfect UI.

Comment: yes i have read lot of answers but still i am not getting it.I haven't found any good article which tell in brief on how to calculate value of margins  for all these devices

Comment: can you post some links of those articles

Comment: https://alvinalexander.com/android/android-screen-sizes-dimensions-xlarge-large-normal-small

Comment: https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-support-multiple-screen-size-in-android/

Comment: you already got so many answer and moreover you still haven't read about sw<dp> notations for designing layouts. The pattern used in the link are deprecated long time ago.

Comment: i have read but ultimately  smallet  screen width is not a challenge but height is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android

Comment: "how can i calculate the values of margin and padding for all views" -- ask the graphic designer. Nobody else can help you understand the design and how to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

You can used this library `'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'` for  size unit scales with the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

its worked for me all screen size supported

To add sdp to your project (Using Android Studio and Gradle):

add implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5' to your build.gradle dependencies block.

for example:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    }
```

and how can you use in project?

in your **xml** just **@dimen/_90sdp insted of 90dp**

it will work good and show good size if you run in **tablet 10 inch** or **3.7 inch phone** 
show nice sorry im learning enlgish :)

its example code :

```
               <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/pic_profile"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"/>
```

also You can use

```
         dependencies {
         implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
          }
```

for font size

its example code for textsize:

```
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
```

Comment: its wrong code? i said if u want use sdp use     implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
in depency 
and i u want change font size add to depency  
         implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
what is wrong code? when it worked in my project?

Comment: I dont want to use library any other best practice?

Comment: you want support all reso screen phone ? right? 
also you can read google document :
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support
AND 
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes 

if its was true tic in my answer ty :)