# Different position on different screen size

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to put a text, a button or something like that in a specific place on an image. But as devices have different screen resolution, the text is changing position and don't remain there where I have positioned it.

That is a view on Nexus 4:

[image: Nexus4]

That is a view on Pixel 2 XL

[image: Pixel2XL]

How can I solve this problem?

tuner_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/manico"
    android:contentDescription="@string/chords" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="81dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="D"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="G"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That's normal in Android because it supports [different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

Comment: Please, provide your layout

Comment: Here an helpful [link](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide) on ImageView properties

Comment: Please provide you xml and java code in which you have used this.

Comment: This is gonna be a bit tricky cause you wanna put stuff in relation to your background image. Is there any rule to how much space these pins (Idk what they're called) take and how much they are from the top/each other etc? If so, you can use `ConstraintLayout` with `Guidelines` set to some values, e.g. to middle of each row of pins and then based on that put the `textviews`.

Comment: Why don't you edit the image to include the string name instead of placing it with the text view?

Comment: @SamuelRobert I want to make it clickable,to play sound on click.If i will draw it on image the problem will be the same :(

Comment: Check below link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using `match_parent` for `ImageView` width,height.
Your `ImageView` will **stretch/skew** based on device screen size, so it won't be possible for you to move your ButtonView accordingly.

However, in this case, you know image dimensions and aspect ratio in advance, you should **create your `ImageView` based on those dimensions(instead of match_parent)**.Now `ImageView` will always maintain the aspect ratio and size and you can position your `TextView,ButtonView` accordingly.