# How to set aspect ratio in xml (dimens.xml in values folder) to set different aspect ratio depending on devices?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, aspect-ratio

Maybe a stupid question but in android how can I set aspect ratio in xml (dimens.xml in values folder) to set different aspect ratio depending on devices

I tried :

layout.xml

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="@dimen/common_image_aspect_ratio"
```

values/dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="common_image_aspect_ratio">3:2</dimen>
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated, thx :)

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android

Comment: @Lucefer thanks for the further information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to write `1.5` instead of `3:2`. Generally, you should use decimal format, not fractional. Hope it will help.

Comment: indeed it was a stupid question I didn't think about it. I'm waiting the 10min before set your answer as correct

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a resource for in the form `3:2` you should use a String:

```xml
// values.xml
<string name="common_image_aspect_ratio">3:2</string>

// layout.xml
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="@string/common_image_aspect_ratio"
```

Using a String also applies when setting a ratio programatically:

```kotlin
 (view.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).dimensionRatio = "3:2"
```