# Which is the best practice to adjust the text size (in a TextView) for different screen sizes

Tags: java, android

How can I avoid overflows in a small screen and small letters in a big
screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define different dimensions for different dpi and resolution in your layout XML files (very useful with tablets!) or you can also use the new Autosizing TextViews available from API 26

Comment: How can I do so?

Comment: You have to create Different values folder for different  screens, You can find more on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android