# How to auto-resize imageview for different screen sizes android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-developer-api

I am starting to develop apps for android devices using Android Studio. While I was testing my app for screen size compatibilty I noticed that the imageviews do not auto-resize.

The imageview placement looks completely different in different screen sizes. If the screen is small enough, the imageview will sometimes be placed outside of the viewscope.

I have looked all over the internet but I am a little confused on how to make the app compatible with most screen sizes (not including tablets). I went to the android website and they said to use wrap_content. but if I use this, I wont be able to adjust the height and width of the imageview to how I want it.

Does anyone know how to make imageview auto-resize accordingly to the screen size?

Here are images of what is happening:

**This is the layout of the app:**

[image: This is the layout]

**This is how I want it to look like (Pixel 3):**

[image]

**But this is how it looks like in a smaller screen(Nexus 5):**

[image]

In Xcode there is a feature called auto-resize that automatically resizes the content for you. Does android studio have something similar to that?

**This is the xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:background="#F70000"
        android:text="Undo"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="248dp"

        android:background="#1750DF"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.685" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*the imageviews do not auto-resize*

Because you are using a fixed size value on your `imageView` you are having this problem:

**Different phones got different screen size**, in your layout you are using fixed size on your view (fixed size is `240dp` for example) and the result is that what may look good on one screen (your android studio preview screen) will not look good on another screen (your actual phone).

---

### How to fix

You can use those attributes to make your image responsive in size:

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
```

**You will need to give your image `0dp` size both in `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`**

What  I did was to tell the view to be equal to `25%` both in width and height according to the screen size, this will make you view responsive to all screen size and thus it will "auto-resize"

Comment: This worked for me. One note, shouldn't this size percentage be based on the parent view and not the screen size view?

Comment: @Andrew Hey, so a bit of a late answer but from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout): **layout_constraintWidth_percent** and **layout_constraintHeight_percent** : will set the size of this dimension as a percentage of the parent

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

Following the answer by @tamir-abutbul , it is a nice workaround to use layout_constraintHeight_percent and layout_constraintWidth_percent to make view fit according to screen size. 
I have placed the top items in a Grid Layout, you can apply this to any of your top layout which you are using, the main thing to consider is the layout_constraintHeight/Width_percent here. 
Also, for the image , I have set the background transparent and changed scaleType to "fitCenter" so that the image keeps its aspect ratio on any screen. hope this helps. You can change android to androidx.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="#faf"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:rowCount="4"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


</GridLayout>

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/lamborghini"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.30"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gridLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.265"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/resetButton"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="#F70000"
    android:text="Undo"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.395" />




 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I believe I have tried this but I still get it in wrong position. Will this change the size of the image view when screen sizes change ? Or will the imageview stay the same size ?

Comment: Can you share your layout xml, because there are techniques to create layouts. Lets see what you are using.

Comment: Hello!, I added the XML code to the question. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong @Adnan

Answer (score 3):

your imageview like that because your define width and height large in other view, so maybe you can try this library for same size in other screen

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: Thank you! This is a great alternative to use as well.