# My layouts aren't scaling properly on low dpi devices

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I made an android app with constrain layout, and the layout doesn't scale properly even thought I've used SP and DP as units.

I double checked all values and they all have dp and sp, I tried it on the following emulators 5.1", pixel, pixel 10"  tablet, pixel 2, pixel 2 XL and the nexus 7

my layouts actually work fine on these, but on the nexus 4 with a smaller dpi it gets ruined.

Edit: even with the cardview constrains set to match_parent, it still doesn't fix it, nothing happens.

as for physical devices, it works fine on my phone with a high dpi of 499, but my two other phones without high dpi, it gets ruined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/withoutgrid">
    <!--grid layout to hold two cards-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:columnOrderPreserved="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.755"
        app:rowCount="1">
        <!--first card layout-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView1"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="290dp"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:onClick="sPlayer"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/backgroundColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/singleplayer"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:onClick="sPlayer"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/robotfinal2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/singleplayertext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="sPlayer"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Single Player"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <!--copy paste for second card layout-->

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

here are some screenshots from 2 same devices one with custom high dpi and another with stock dpi

[image: high dpi] [image: low dpi]

[image: Emulator]

Comment: Is this your full xml ?

Comment: looks like you providing hard coded dp values which causing problem on small devices so you can opt for using dimen file as per device dpi check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android

Comment: @TamirAbutbul edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issues here is that you are testing the layout on small screen sizes such as the Nexus 4 which is about 4.7 inches.

You probably did not develop the application with the initial design focused on such a small screen size.

Consider creating alternate layouts for different screen sizes.

Supporting different screen sizes would help.

Check this link out:
[Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

Comment: hmm, I get it, but my grid layout's width is set to match_parent, so it should be the grid layout which is in fault right? how do I fix the cardView dynamically? even with match_parent nothing happens on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Guideline in the center of the screen to make this go easier and it works for me, try to use this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```