# Are these layouts enough to scale images for smaller DPI devices?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, layout, android-imageview

Make copy of main activity file in the following folders.

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml
res/layout-w600dp/main_activity.xml
res/layout-large/main_activity.xml
res/layout-xlarge/main_activity.xml
```

And resize my images from drawable and place them into these folders

```
ldpi     (~120dpi).
mdpi     (~160dpi).
hdpi    (~240dpi).
xhdpi     (~320dpi).
xxhdpi     (~480dpi).
xxxhdpi (~640dpi).
```

Is this enough to make my app scale properly for phones with lower resolution?

Comment: I dont know whether you are going to accept. My thought is there is no harm in avoiding phone with low resolution (mdpi & ldpi) even you are trying to make consumer based application.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply but my app isn't scaling properly for normal dpi as well, here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571547/my-layouts-arent-scaling-properly-on-low-dpi-devices so someone suggested I do this instead so I wanted to know if these folders are enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, after a lot of experimentation the layouts seem to work, all I had to do was make seperate folders for them.