# dimens.xml for all screen sizes

Tags: android, fold, split-screen

I am supporting split screen in my application. I want the imageview size to be set from dimens.xml when the width changes. If the screen width = 275 , the app is taking textview size from dimens.xml . How can I make app to take the imageview size from different dimens.xml if the screen width is 275dp, 320dp because the screen width varies when user changes the screen size in split screen ?

Comment: There are multiple answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android or the official docs: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: use ssp and sdp dependency

Answer (score 0):

You should create new values resources directory, like `values-w275dp` and `values-w320dp`.
This will be applied for screens with exact width. It's better to use **`Smallest Screen Width`**

- Right click on `res` -> `New` -> `Android Resource Directory`
- Set `Resource type` to `values`
- Select `Available qualifiers` - `Screeh Width`
- Click `>>`
- Set desirable screen width

[image]

Comment: In reality he should be using `smallest screen width` to be safer

Comment: @MatPag yes, it will be definitely better

Comment: @MatPag I did as you said, creating the dimens.xml (sw-275) but the app takes dimensions from . dimens.xml (sw-275) even in normal mode i.e not split-mode instead of taking from dimens.xml

Comment: @Vinay the folders should be in this form: `values-swXdp` where X is DP value, and you can add a custom `dimens.xml` in each of them

Comment: @MatPag i did as you said. I define a dimens.xml in values-swXdp. Even when the screen is not in split screen , app takes dimensions from values-sw255dp. I want the app to take values from different folders based on screen size.

Comment: You probably need to create more folders, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51709197/2910520 and you should test on which folder your device fall to, this depends on the screen DP available