# Android Normal Layout is displayed differently on devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm relatively new in the area of App Development and still cant get behind the proper way to set up an xml file (in this case for a normal layout) to fit every mobile device that uses this layout type.

For example: I have a Pixel 2 Emulator and a Nexus 5 Emulator (both use the normal layout). However the result on the screen looks different on the devices:

Pixel 2 (1080x1920 - 420dpi): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zmZ3.png

Nexus 5 (1080x1920 - xxhdpi): https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSLtb.png

After some research in the Google developers section about Device compability I found out that it could be due to the different pixel densities, but I have no clue how to fix this.

The xml code of this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mybackground"
    tools:context=".Start">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_below="@id/name_add"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:width="180dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textColorHint="#424242"
        app:backgroundTint="#585858" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/name_add"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/name_add"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="add"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goToSelection"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
        android:background="@drawable/play_btn"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_play"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/languagegbr"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gbr"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/languagedr"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/germanyr"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

All of the images will later be replaced by vector graphics.

My question now is, how I can make my layout on the Nexus 5 (and on any other mobile device with a resolution of 1080x1920 or that uses the normal layout in general) look the same as it looks on the Pixel 2?

Comment: Instead of adding margin, center the textview in layout

Comment: good point @GabrieleMariotti, but if I want to add like 2 more buttons under the play button the second will be cut off at the bottom by the screen off the Nexus 5, so there is still an arrangement issue

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62485947/8244632) answer on a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've **struggled** with this kind of issues for a long time.

This stuff happens when you mess too much with dp's in margins and paddings usually. Given that dp's stay **almost equal** between different phone sizes, you will get variations of your display, such as the one you're showing us.

The way I solved it is by using Constraint Layout. It's very simple to use, and it has a lot of advantages. If there's no particular reason why you're not using Constraint Layout I highly suggest you to start now.

In a Constraint Layout all you need to do for your error to be solved is set the horizontal constraints to the parent and that's it.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".login.YourActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>   

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Just by saying you'll be attached to your parent's left and right, sets the view right in the middle of your screen. Of any screen actually.

Comment: Well, I just changed everything to Constraint Layout and it works the way I wanted it to. Thank you, the problem were indeed the dp margins.

Comment: Great! If you ever wonder about animations remember to look up Motion Layout.