# Android Studio reusable xml value

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I've got this super simple question I can't find an answer to.
I want to make a variable which I could then use for multiple elements.
Something like this in strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="textSize">20sp</string>
</resources>
...
<EditText android:textSize="@string/textSize" />
```

But this does not work.
I was able to accomplish what I wanted the following way in themes.xml:

```
<style name="textSize">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
...
<EditText android:theme="@style/textSize" />
```

But it seems too complicated for just a single value, is there a better way?

Comment: If you're wanting a dimension resource, you need to specify a `dimen`, not `string`. So `<dimen name="my_dimension">20sp</dimen>`

Comment: Please try this,
"    <style name="CustomEditText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">        
       <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/sp_20</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/editTextColor</item>
    </style>"

Comment: @HenryTwist That works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this looks like a `dimen` property rather than a `string`.

Just like `strings.xml`, you can have another file (usually `dimen.xml`) with dimensions. Your case could look like this:

```xml
<resources>
    <dimen name="bigText">20sp</string>
</resources>
```

It also allows you to have different settings for different configurations (for example, screen sizes here: [How to define dimens.xml for every different screen size in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android)).

You can find the documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources?hl=en#Dimension