# Create a menu xml like chorme

Tags: java, android, menu

I want to create menu `xml` like chorme. How can i do this? 
I tried this but doesn't show any icon :(

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_more"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="More apps"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_rate"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Rate this app"/>


</menu>
```

[image: android chorme]

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722907/how-to-split-the-menu-like-chrome

Comment: I dont think so chorme is using dialog fragment.

Comment: without using this how can we develop that dialog